# Image sampling using PyMC

Tags: probability, sampling, pymc

I want to sample images using MCMC Random Walk algorithm. How does MCMC sample images, if model parameters is a vector(bounding boxes of objects, centers of mass and etc.)

Comment: Are you just asking for code? (If so , that would be off topic here.) If you are wondering how a random walk can be used to sample images (irrespective of software), please edit to clarify.

Comment: @gung I wanted to ask for explanation of this algorithm for images, and also some code examples, because I didnt find them.

Comment: Code examples are off topic. The explanation isn't. Please edit your Q to clarify the on topic question.

Comment: @gung I changed my question. So, do you know anything about sampling images? Or where can I find code examples with generating matrices.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't.